# Delete repeated words in a row Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

it turns out that I'm using beautifulsoup and when filtering in a table, I got the data as follows:

```
["<td>9111/2018 2222/18</td>", '<td style="font-size: small;">AINDUSTRIAL </td>', 
 "<td>18-05-2018</td>", "<td>Juz. 5 Posá<td>POSA</td></td>", 
 "<td>POSA</td>"]
```

I need to extract only the `"<td>"` that says `"Juz 5. Posá"` (although for what I'm doing, the name will vary) but I just need that column. I leave the code, since I managed to make the output is:

```
Juz. 5 PosáPOSA
```

I just need Juz. 5 Posá, but unfortunately I hit that other word. Then the code, of course, thank you very much!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,from_encoding="utf-8")

table = soup.findChildren('table')[0]
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    col = row.find_all("td")
    print(col[3].text.replace('\n',''))
    if not cells:
        continue
```

Comment: *Not really the problem*: `continue` does nothing instead skipping to next iteration without executing statements following it. You don't seem to have any statements after to skip if the condition is satisfied though.

Comment: But, why beautifulsoup filters me <td> Juz. 5 Post <td> POSA </ td> </ td> if in fact, in the table, they are separated: <td> Juz. 5 Posá <td> POSA </ td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this what you are looking for but here are two solution.

Solution # 1

Recurively remove the characters "<, >, /, td"

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  x = x.replace("<", "")
  x = x.replace(">", "")
  x = x.replace("/", "")
  x = x.replace("td", "")
print(x)
```

## OR

Solution #2

First Select the list item[3]

```
x = x[3]
```

Select the first 4 character from the string because it starts with

```
x = x[4:]
```

Then find the index of "<" because the next td tag will start with < and remove everything after the < index

```
print(x[:x.index("<")])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but... i've realized how the html is brought, and what happens is that what I see is that it does not close a td, that is, it checks the td that I put and you will notice that "<td> Juz 5 Posá < td> POSA </ td> </ td> "is not closing a td that is what I require, some way to solve it?

Comment: My God, as I wrote what you put me, I had not tried. Now that I try, it works correctly. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Seriously, I was stuck. I'm really surprised that it was only with a .replace. Again thank you very much @MFK34